# How to set IN AN ARRAY a key's value, using another key

Tags: php, arrays

i want to set one key's value to another key's value + some string

i tried this

```
    $b = array ( 
      'name'        => 'Gilbert',
      'fullname '   => $b['name']. 'Hocvinger',
       );

echo $b['fullname'];
```

but it gives me an error.

Comment: It doesn't work like this, because the array has not been defined yet. You'd need to define the name outside of the array decleration, and then you can add it to the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not act like this way since during definition of array it's fields are inaccessible because array is *not defined yet*.

But you can easily do that after array's definition, like:

```
$b = array('name' => 'Gilbert');
$b['fullname'] = $b['name'].' Hocvinger';
```

Answer (score 4):

you can do this after initializing the array

```
$b = array ( 
      'name' => 'Gilbert'
);

$b['fullname ']  = $b['name']. 'Hocvinger';

echo $b['fullname'];
```